# Solr Stats on Tuple

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-startup

I'm trying to use the [Stats Component](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) in my Datastax Solr instance.

The part of the schema I'm trying to get stats on looks like this:

```
<field name="foo" type="tuple" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="foo.start" type="bigint" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="foo.end" type="bigint" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="foo.time" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

However, when I try and use `stats=true&stats.field={!tuple}foo.time` with a `*:*` query I get the following:

```
 "stats": {
    "stats_fields": {
      "foo.time": null
    }
  }
```

Is it not possible to use a `{!tuple}` for stats?

Comment: This is currently not supported unfortunately. Still you may contact Datastax support for further info.

Comment: Thanks, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported unfortunately. Still you may contact Datastax support for further info.